# I'm trying to manage common variable between PHP modules using the $_SESSION using INCLUDE files in each of the modules

Tags: php

I have four PHP modules/forms which use common variables.  I'm trying to use include files with Session Start and $_SESSION to pass with same data between modules. But when I use it I get

Notice: Undefined index: Cot in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Ironman2014Test\includes\Session_to_Variable_PHP.inc.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: Tent_Time_In in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Ironman2014Test\includes\Session_to_Variable_PHP.inc.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: Tent_Time_Out in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Ironman2014Test\includes\Session_to_Variable_PHP.inc.php on line 5

I can not seem to make these errors go away.

Comment: They're not errors. They're warnings. You're trying to access session variables that don't exist. In other words, you need to test for the EXISTENCE of those variables with isset() before you try to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['Cot']))
{
   echo $_SESSION['Cot'];
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Cot']))
{
   echo $_SESSION['Cot'];
}
```